# jQuery: Make a letter within a string blinking

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas

I want to make a textadventure with Canvas and the parser should be blinking permanently like the parser within a Dos Console. The parser is saved as a global variable. What should I do to change the character of the global variable via jQuery permanently?

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas'),
    context = canvas.getContext('2d'),
    string = '',     //Empty string which combines command, parser and '>' character
    start_cmd ='>',  //The character '>' starts before the command
    command = '',    //Typed characters
    parser = '_';   //Parser which appears at the end of 'command'

    $(document).on('keypress', function(event) {
        string = start_cmd + command + parser;
        $(document).clear();                //Self declared function which makes the whole canvas white.    
        $(document).drawConsole();          //Self declared function which draws the console.   
        $(document).println(string, 10, 550);//Self declared function which writes what you last typed in the keyboard.

        switch (event.which)
        {           
            case 8:
                    command = command.slice(0, -1);             
                    $(document).clear();
                    $(document).drawConsole();  
                    break;
            case 13:
                    command = '';
                    $(document).clear();
                    $(document).drawConsole();          
                    break;
            default:
                    if (command.length < 46)
                    {
                        $(document).clear();
                        $(document).drawConsole();                      
                        command += String.fromCharCode(event.which);                        
                    }           
                    break;
        }
            string = start_cmd + command + parser;

            $(document).println(string, 10, 550);       
            console.log(event.which);
    });
});
```

Comment: What have you tried already? How does your code look like so far? What problems have you encountered? Try to address these question for others to be able to help you.

Comment: Can you show us some code?

Comment: So, I've added my code in a shortened form. The self declared functions have nothing to do with the parser variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best place for implementing this would possibly be in your `println()` method. You can create an interval that removes the last character from your string - which will always be the `_`, or adds it.

```js
let visible = true;
setInterval(() => {
  let t = document.getElementById('foo');
  visible = !visible;
  t.innerText = visible ? t.innerText.trim().slice(0, -1) : (t.innerText + "_");
}, 200);
```

```html
<div id="foo">
  foo
</div>
```